# How to know from which perl module or file the function was called

Tags: perl

I need to know from which perl file my function was called. Let's say I have the following module (`MyModule.pm`) which has the following function:

```
package MyModule;

sub myFunc{
   # Here I need to print the name of the file that the function was called from
}
```

And the script `myScript.pl` uses `MyModule` and calls the function `myFunc()`:

```
use MyModule;
MyModule->myFunc();
```

I need the call to `myFunc()` here to print "`myScript.pl`"

Is there any way to do this in Perl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside method,

```
sub myFunc{
  my ($package, $filename, $line) = caller;
  print $filename;
}
```

Check [`perldoc -f caller`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/caller.html) for more details.